# Tab completion COMP_WORDS bad array subscript

Tags: 10.04, bash

I have upgraded my Ubuntu to 10.04 and I am facing this problem of COMP_WORDS bad array subscript when I press TAB for certain completion. I thought, it is a bug with bash-completion package and I purged it. But even after that, I still face this. If it is a bug with bash package, how I can resolve it?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/366446

It is difficult for a developer to live with this bug in the system.

Comment: I'm getting this and doing `bash` fixes it for me. But still annoying.

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround could be using another shell like [fish](http://fishshell.org/index.php).